# How to use two different AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID & SECRET_KEY in one project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

We have already used AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID & SECRET_KEY in this method

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID secretKey:SECRET_KEY];

}
```

it is working perfect , but now there is a need to use another ACCESS_KEY_ID & SECRET_KEY and different Bucket (along with old ACCESS_KEY_ID & SECRET_KEY )

it could not able to run , throwing an error

Please guide us ,How to use two different ACCESS_KEY_ID & SECRET_KEY and Bucket in project

-Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to create 2 build schemes for this or you want both keys to be used in same time ?

Comment: Dear @RahulVyas 
I would like to use the two different keys in two methods

Comment: you can set credentials and bucket path, based on build flag; for #DEBUG you can set development else production AWS credentials/path

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 build schemes/environments. Follow this article it's very well explained. The article is for firebase but you can use it for AWS json file as well.

[Multiple build environment](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0)

Comment: Dear Rahul Vyas 
Thanks for your reply and time .
I found the refresh concept at AWS documentation .
refresh – Forces a refresh of the stored/cache credentials. Depending on your implementation, this may or may not be necessary (for instance, the AmazonStaticCredentialsProvider treats this as a no-op).

[[[[[AWSS3 defaultS3] configuration] credentialsProvider] credentials] waitUntilFinished];

but it could not work , Please guide me 
-Thanks

Comment: can you send me the article you're following ?

Comment: Dear Rahul Vyas 
Thanks for your reply 

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-amazoncredentialsprovider-protocol-in-the-aws-sdk-for-ios/

Here , I could find about : Refresh 
-Thanks

Comment: this article is not useful in your case. The only thing you need to do is create multiple build schemes as I told you earlier and you can use xconfig file as well. ping me over skype I'll show you. This is my skype Id - imrahulvyas@gmail.com